# Graphs that are connected vs strongly connected vs reachable

Tags: graphs

What is the difference between "connected", "strongly connected", and "reachable" in a graph?

Answer (score 5):

**Connected**: Usually associated with undirected graphs (two way edges): There is a path between every two nodes.

**Strongly connected**: Usually associated with directed graphs (one way edges): There is a route between every two nodes (route ~ path in each direction between each pair of vertices).

**Reachable** (from $A$ to $B$): A path exists in the graph between nodes $A$ and $B$. (Ability to get from one vertex to another)

Note: Got some terminology from:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6833/difference-between-connected-vs-strongly-connected-vs-complete-graphs

Comment: **route** is an unusual word to use. See wiki page [strongly connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) to realise route here means a path for **each direction**.